# How to solve this ellipse problem?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Assume that ellipse $C:\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1(a>b>0)$, its left focus is $F$, the line $l$ passing $F$ intersects the ellipse $C$ at $A$ and $B$. The angle of inclination of $l$ is $\frac{\pi}{3}$, and $\overrightarrow{AF}=2\overrightarrow{FB}$.

If $|AB|=\frac{15}{4}$, how to solve the equation of $C$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the assumption we have: $AF=\frac{10}{4}$ and $BF=\frac{5}{4}$.

We have that left focus is $F=(-c,0)$ where $c^2=a^2-b^2$. Consider the left directrix $d:\ x=-\frac{a}{e}$, where $e= \frac{c}{a}$ is the eccentricity, and drop perpendiculars $A',F',B'$ from $A,F,B$ to $d$. The quadrilateral $AA'B'B$ is a trapezoid with the angle $\angle BAA'=60^\circ$, right angles at vertices $A'$ and $B'$, and basis $AA'=\frac{1}{e}AF=\frac{10}{4e}$ and $BB'=\frac{1}{e}BF= \frac{5}{4e}$. Then we easily see (by dropping a perpendicular from $B$ to $AA'$) that $AA'-BB'=AB\cos 60^\circ$, so $\frac{5}{4e}=\frac{15}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{2}$, wherefrom $e=\frac{2}{3}$. Therefore, $AA'=\frac{15}{4}$ and $BB'=\frac{15}{8}$.

Since parallel line  $FF'$ to the basis of the trapezoid divides $AB$ in the ratio $2:1$ we have: $FF'=\frac{1}{3}(AA'+2BB')$, i.e. $\frac{a}{e}-c= \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{30}{4}= \frac{10}{4}$, i.e. $\frac{a}{e}-ae=a(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{2}{3})=\frac{10}{4}$, wherefrom $a=3$. Now, $c=ae=2$, and $b=\sqrt{a^2-c^2}=\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Interesting approach. A little figure could help to follow... I am going to write down a different solution, with the same results !

Comment: Such an interesting solution! Thank you!

Comment: @SMM Thanks to you, I have been able to use as well the directrix for a (second) solution that is based on different results from yours (for example, I dont use the eccentricity). Your opinion ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Very nice! It seems that qadrics have immense number of very nice properties, and most of them are not commonly known.

Comment: @SMM Yes not known because no longer taught for now half a century. In the first half of the XXth century, in my country, France, they were at the center of the teaching in the final years of high school and at the collegial level. Maybe it was exaggerate ; but now on, the pendulum has gone in a completely reverse sense...  although the basic properties of these curves are essential to know, especialy in Physics.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Fig. 1 :*This figure illustrates the 2 answers I give as well as the very interesting answer by @SMM. On the left is figured the directrix line associated with focus $F$. See comments at the end of the first solution.*

**First method**

Let us use the following parameterization of the ellipse :

$$\begin{cases}x=a \cos(t)\\y=b \sin(t)\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

Let

$$\begin{cases}t_1, c_1=\cos(t_1), s_1=\sin(t_1) \ \text{correspond to point } \ A \\t_2, c_2=\cos(t_2), s_2=\sin(t_2) \ \ \text{correspond to point } \ B\end{cases}$$

The following system of 6 equations with 6 unknowns takes into account the different constraints of the problem :

$$\begin{cases}\frac{b(s_1-s_2)}{a(c_1-c_2)}&=&\sqrt{3}& \ \ \ \ (a)\\
    a^2(c_2-c_1)^2+b^2(s_2-s_1)^2&=&(\tfrac{15}{4})^2& \ \ \ \ (b)\\
    a\frac{c_1+2c_2}{3}&=&-\sqrt{a^2-b^2}& \ \ \ \ (c)\\
2s_2+s_1&=&0& \ \ \ \ (d)\\
s_1^2+c_1^2&=&1& \ \ \ \ (e)\\
s_2^2+c_2^2&=&1& \ \ \ \ (f)\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

**Explanations :**

(a) for the slope $\tan(\tfrac{\pi}{3})=\sqrt{3},$

(b) for $\|\overrightarrow{AB}\|^2=(\tfrac{15}{4})^2,$

(c) and (d) for relationship $\tfrac{A+2B}{3}=F$, knowing that the coordinates of this focus are $(c,0)=(-\sqrt{a^2-b^2},0).$

No comment for (e) and (f).

I have used a CAS for solving this system, but it could be done by hand (for example, one can at once get rid of $s_1$ using eq. (1)d).

The solutions of system (1) are :

$$a=3, \ b=\sqrt{5}, \ c_1=-1/4,  \  c_2=-7/8, \ s_1 =-\sqrt{15}/4, \ \ s_2=\sqrt{15}/8$$

giving the following equation :

$$\dfrac{x^2}{9}+\dfrac{y^2}{5}=1$$

and the following coordinates for points $A, B, F$:

$$A=(a c_1,b s_1)=(-21/8,-5\sqrt{3}/8),  \ \  \ \ B=(a c_2,b s_2)=(-3/4,5\sqrt{3}/4)$$

and $F=(-\sqrt{a^2-b^2},0)=(-2,0).$

Remarks : First, a point of vocabulary : a chord like $AB$ passing through one of the focii is called a **focal chord**. One can prove that the **pole** $P$ of a focal chord (intersection of the tangents in $A$ and $B$) is situated on the directrix. More precisely, the directrix associated with $F$ can be described as the locus of poles of all focal chords passing through $F$. Moreover $PF \perp AB$ ; an old reference about all that : https://archive.org/stream/geometricaltreat00drewuoft/geometricaltreat00drewuoft#page/38/mode/1up. 
This gives :

**2nd method of solution :**

Let us first recall that the tangent to an ellipse with equation $\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ at point $(x_k,y_k)$ has the following equation

$$\dfrac{xx_k}{a^2}+\dfrac{yy_k}{b^2}=1.\tag{3}$$

Let us now write the equation of the ellipse under a form that will be more handy for expressing constraints:

$$ux^2+vy^2=1 \ \ \text{with} \ \ u:=1/a^2, v:=1/b^2.\tag{4}$$

Let us denote by $(x_0,y_0)$ the coordinates of point $P$ (the so-called "pole").

Then, the unknowns, that are different from the unknowns of system (2), verify :

$$\begin{cases}
     y_1-y_2&=&\sqrt{3}(x_1-x_2)& \ \ \ \ (a)\\
    (x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2&=&225/16& \ \ \ \ (b)\\
    (2x_1+x_2)/3&=&f& \ \ \ \ (c)\\
     2y_1+y_2&=&0& \ \ \ \ (d)\\
    (x_0-f)(x_1-x_2)+y_0(y_1-y_2)&=&0& \ \ \ \ (e)\\
    ux_0x_1+vy_0y_1&=&1& \ \ \ \ (f)\\
    ux_0x_2+vy_0y_2&=&1& \ \ \ \ (g)\\
    ux_1^2+vy_1^2&=&1& \ \ \ \ (h)\\
    ux_2^2+vy_2^2&=&1& \ \ \ \ (i)\end{cases}\tag{5}$$

Explanations :

(a), (b), (c), (d) : same constraints as in system (2).

(e) : orthogonality between PF and AB.

(f) : $P=(x_0,y_0)$ is on the tangent in $A(x_1,y_1)$ (using (3)).

(g) : In the same way, $P=(x_0,y_0)$ is on the tangent in $B(x_2,y_2)$.

(h) and (i) : $A$ and  $B$ belong to the ellipse.

System (5), although bigger than system (2) (9 equations with 9 unknowns) is easily solved by a CAS, or even by hand. It gives in particular

$$P(x_0,y_0)=(-9/2,5\sqrt{3}/6).$$

Comment: I have added a picture. Could you say if my solution is understandable ?

Comment: Whoa, I think I've understand it properly, with so many details, thank you for your time! I appreciate it very much!

Comment: Sorry, I calculate it again, the result of a should be 3, and b is square root 5, I'm trying to find something that may cause the problem.

Comment: Thus you find all multiplied by 2. If you photograph a piece of paper with your calculations, I can maybe localize where the problem is.

Comment: I'll try it, maybe it costs a long time for me to write down, really sorry to bother you.

Comment: You don't bother me. I'm happy to help students.

Comment: Sorry, but when your answer comes to (d) equation, it's $\frac{-3\sqrt{15}}{8}$, some other equation are also have some problems.

Comment: You are perfectly right. I find now the same results as you and SMM. I correct it. and I give a new figure. Very sorry for these calculation errors.

Comment: I should thank you for you patience to teach me the way to solve in parameter equation way, it's useful for me which has profound meaning. Again, really thanks! It's night time in Asia and hope you can have a good day.  :)

Comment: Thanks. Corrected version.

Comment: 6:30 pm in France right now.

Comment: 2:30 am in Tokyo, have a good night in advance! Bon soir :)

Comment: I have improved the figure for 2 reasons : a) it shows that the pole of a focal chord is on the directrix of this focus b) it may help in the understanding of the interesting solution by @SMM. See the remarks at the bottom of the text.

Comment: @SMM use the property of the proportional in focus chord. This time I think I would have a deep impression.  Interesting property of the focus chord, a lot of things for me to discover, thank you!

Comment: I have provided a second method of solution.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to understand it.

Comment: I have a small question, what is CAS? I search it on google but nothing is useful

Comment: CAS : Computer Algebra System. See for example : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system